# How to dynamically change the content of CALayer

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, calayer

I am creating some CALayers and transforming them using CATransform3D using

```
imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(-22.0f, 188.0f, 180.0f, 50.0f);
imageLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(120.0f * M_PI / 180.0f,
                                                 0.0f, 15.0f, 0.0f);
imageLayer.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.png"] CGImage];
[caLayer addSublayer:imageLayer];
```

here is an sample image with the output...
[image]

I have kept the untransformed image as image view so that i can handle swipes. I have an array of 10 images. So, when a user swipes on the main images the corresponding images should load up in the layers and image view. I can load the image view but had some problems loading the CALayers dynamically.

I have tried

```
NSArray *array=[caLayer sublayers];
    caLayer = [array objectAtIndex:entryImageIndex];
    //caLayer.contents=(id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"flashImage1.jpg"] CGImage];
    caLayer.contents=(id)[[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[imageArray objectAtIndex:entryImageIndex-1]]];
```

But this gave me errors. Can anyone plz tell me how to populate the CALayers dynamically with images...Any sample code will be of great help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
    caLayer.contents=(id)[[UIImage imageWithCGImage:
[imageArray objectAtIndex:entryImageIndex-1]
]
];
```

try

```
    caLayer.contents=(id)[UIImage imageWithCGImage:
[imageArray objectAtIndex:entryImageIndex-1]
].CGImage;
```

or

```
caLayer.contents=(id)[imageArray objectAtIndex:entryImageIndex-1];
```